# how to find and replace a string in .reg files using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to open a .reg file and replace a particular string with another.I am using the below code(replace.vbs) and i am getting a "Invalid procedural call or argument" error and the .reg file is getting empty once i run this code.This code works fine for text files but not for .reg.please help me to figure out where I am going wrong.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

strFileName = Wscript.Arguments(0)
strOldText = Wscript.Arguments(1)
strNewText = Wscript.Arguments(2)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, strOldText, strNewText)

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close
```

I run this in cmd `CSCRIPT replace.vbs "this.reg" "KEY" "1234"` and this.reg is getting empty.Thanks in advance.

Comment: By default, `.reg` files are UNICODE with [byte order mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) of `FFFE`, i.e. `UTF-16 (LE)`. Force `OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForReading, , OpenAsUnicode)` with `Const OpenAsUnicode=-1`. Analogously for output file. Make sure the BOM bytes are present in output.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this to auto-detect the encoding and open the file accordingly:

```
Function ReadFile(filename)
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  bom = ""
  Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)
  Do Until f.AtEndOfStream Or bom = "ÿþ" Or bom = "þÿ" Or Len(bom) >= 3
    bom = bom & f.Read(1)
  Loop
  f.Close

  Select Case bom
    Case "ÿþ", "þÿ"  'UTF-16 text
      Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 1, False, -1)
      ReadFile = f.ReadAll
      f.Close
    Case "ï»¿"       'UTF-8 text
      Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
      stream.Open
      stream.Type = 2
      stream.Charset = "utf-8"
      stream.LoadFromFile filename
      ReadFile = stream.ReadText
      stream.Close
    Case Else        'ASCII text
      Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 1, False, 0)
      ReadFile = f.ReadAll
      f.Close
  End Select
End Function

reg = ReadFile("C:\path\to\your.reg")
```