# how to find and replace a string in .reg files using vbscript - Follow-through

Tags: vbscript, windows-7, registry

I found someone else that posted my exact same question but the answer leaves a lot to be desired for someone rather new like me:

[how to find and replace a string in .reg files using vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181467/how-to-find-and-replace-a-string-in-reg-files-using-vbscript)

I attempted to add to the code but naturally I just get errors when I run it. How do I go ahead and execute the find and replace in that scenario:

```
Function ReadFile(filename)
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

bom = ""
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream Or bom = "ÿþ" Or bom = "þÿ" Or Len(bom) >= 3
bom = bom & f.Read(1)
Loop
f.Close

Select Case bom
Case "ÿþ", "þÿ"  'UTF-16 text
  Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 1, False, -1)
  ReadFile = f.ReadAll
  f.Close
Case "ï»¿"       'UTF-8 text
  Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  stream.Open
  stream.Type = 2
  stream.Charset = "utf-8"
  stream.LoadFromFile filename
  ReadFile = stream.ReadText
  stream.Close
Case Else        'ASCII text
  Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 1, False, 0)
  ReadFile = f.ReadAll
  f.Close
 End Select
 End Function

 reg = ReadFile("C:\temp\File.reg")

 userName = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%") newString = Replace(oldString, "domain\user" , userName)

 End Function
```

Comment: This part of the line does the replacing `Replace(oldString, "domain\user" , userName)
`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. The issue I'm having is the inability to execute the script so that it replaces and saves the .reg file.